# android-maven-plugin - How to set up apkMetaIncludes?

Tags: android, android-maven-plugin

http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn/apk-mojo.html#apkMetaIncludes

> Pattern for additional META-INF resources to be packaged into the apk.
>   The APK builder filters these resources and doesn't include them into
>   the apk. This leads to bad behaviour of dependent libraries relying on
>   these resources, for instance service discovery doesn't work. By
>   specifying this pattern, the android plugin adds these resources to
>   the final apk. The pattern is relative to META-INF, i.e. one must use:

```
<apkMetaIncludes>
    <metaInclude>services/**</metaInclude>
</apkMetaIncludes>
```

The META-INF folder is under src folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.alpha9.teste</groupId>
    <artifactId>testemvn</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>testemvn</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                    <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                    <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                    <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                    <sdk>
                        <path>/Applications/android-sdk-macosx</path>
                        <platform>13</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                    <apkMetaIncludes>
                        <metaInclude>services/**</metaInclude>
                    </apkMetaIncludes>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

At the end, my APK has no services folder!

Comment: Did you find the answer to this question? I have the exact same problem. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually wrong in the javadoc. I will fix it. In the meantime this should work

```
<configuration>
  <apk>
    <metaIncludes>
      <metaInclude>services/**</metaInclude>
    </metaIncludes>
  </apk>
</configuration>
```

Of course I would also welcome feedback/confirmation that it works and potentially a pull request that updates the docs..

Comment: I just checked the code. There might be some more work required to get this right..

Comment: should either of these configurations work in 3.5.3? (because neither is working for me ...)

Comment: ok, so my particular problem is that it does copy META-INF entries from dependency jars but not from android library projects.